# Nginx reverse server takes to long to reverse to angular2 live development server

Tags: angular, nginx, reverse-proxy

We have a special requirement that I have to put Angular2 Live Development Server (`ng serve`) behind a reverse proxy during the development.

**My Environment:**

OS: Windows 10

Angular version: 5

Nginx: 1.14.0

Angular Cli: 1.7.0

Angular Live Development Server runs on http://localhost:7776

Nginx Proxy Server runs on http://localhost:7777

**My Problem:**

if I access 7776 directly without the proxy it loads very fast within 1 seconds, however if access from 7777 (reverse proxy) it takes about 1 mins to complete the loading.

**My nginx.conf:**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       7777;
        server_name  localhost;

        charset utf-8;

        location /sockjs-node {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7776/sockjs-node;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }


        location / {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7776;
        }
    }
}
```

**Chrome Console:**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed all `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` which solved my problem.